# DirectorySearcher() and AuthenticationTypes Enum

Tags: active-directory, ldap

When instantiating **DirectorySearcher(doman,...)** with params you can specify the **AuthenticationTypes**.
However, when instantiating **DirectorySearcher()** without params, it is not clear what **AuthenticationTypes** will be used.

This is now a big deal as the **AuthenticationTypes.secure** which uses NTLM will be abandoned and disabled on MS AD servers by MS next few months.. which leaves developers scrambling to un-F their SW

My guess is when instantiating DirectorySearcher() without params, the calling code will find the first suitable AuthenticationType, so existing code will not break.  But I would like confirmation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is `AuthenticationTypes.Secure`, which you can see from the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.DirectoryServices/System/DirectoryServices/DirectoryEntry.cs,34) or by examining the `AuthenticationType` property:

```
Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryEntry().AuthenticationType);
```

However, `AuthenticationTypes.Secure` does not *only* try NTLM. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes) says:

> Requests secure authentication. When this flag is set, the WinNT provider uses NTLM to authenticate the client. Active Directory Domain Services uses Kerberos, and possibly NTLM, to authenticate the client. When the user name and password are a null reference (`Nothing` in Visual Basic), ADSI binds to the object using the security context of the calling thread, which is either the security context of the user account under which the application is running or of the client user account that the calling thread is impersonating.

In the case of Active Directory Domain Services, it will actually prefer Kerberos over NTLM.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean that when MS implements their new hardening, the default security will fail?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirement-for-windows

Comment: I don't see anything in that link that suggests that any legitimate request will fail that previously didn't.